# Remove line breaks and add BR tags in PHP

Tags: php, html

I have the following text for which I would like to add a `<br>` tag between every paragraph. And also remove all the line breaks. How would I do this in PHP? Thanks.

So this -

```
This is some text
for which I would
like to remove 
the line breaks.

And I would also 
like to place
a b>  tag after 
every paragraph.

Here is one more
paragraph.
```

Would become this -

```
This is some text for which I would like to remove the line breaks.<br/> And I would also like to place a br tag after every paragraph. <br> Here is one more paragraph.
```

NOTE: Ignore the highlighting of any letters.

Comment: Did you intentionally use two different styles of `br` tag?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

That should work, too: (though simplistic)

```
$string = str_replace("\n\n", "<br />", $string);
$string = str_replace("\n", "", $string);
```

It was tested.

Answer (score 7):

Well, it seems that you consider a paragraph delimiter, an empty line. So the easiest solution seems this:

```
$text  = str_replace( "\r", "", $text ); // this removes the unwanted \r
$lines = explode( "\n", $text ); // split text into lines.
$textResult = "";
foreach( $lines AS $line )
{
   if( trim( $line ) == "" ) $textResult .= "<br />";
   $textResult .= " " . $line;
}
```

I think this solves your problem. `$textResult` would have your result

Comment: +1 Ah finally, someone with some sense! I haven't tested so it better work otherwise I'll be back!

Answer (score 4):

Either I'm missing something or no one gave the simplest solution possible -- built-in function [`nl2br`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.nl2br.php):

```
echo nl2br($string);
```

Only remember, that if you're using pure string (not a variable) as `nl2br`'s argument, you must use double quotes or else your control characters, like `\n` or `\r` won't be expanded.

Answer (score 0):

```
echo str_replace(array("\n\n", "\n"), array("<br/>", " "), $subject);
```

The above replaces double-newlines with the `<br/>` tag and any left-over single newlines into a space (to avoid words originally only separated by a newline from running into one another).

Would you have any need to cater for CRLF (windows) style line breaks; that would slightly (though not drastically) change the approach.

Comment: this seems right also, but I figured you can't tell if on the empty line there's a space or not, or if there are any \r chars

Comment: @Gabriel: absolutely, we can only do the best with what the question-asker gives us.

Answer (score 0):

This does it for me

`$string = ereg_replace( "\n", "<br/>", $string);`