# Replacing a line break with <br /> tag before submitting the form?

Tags: php, html, forms

I have a text field in my form which asks the user to enter his/her info. I want that when i submit the form, the entered data has all line breaks replaced with a `<br />` tag so that when this data is stored in the database and displayed later then the formatting is correct.

```
<form action="index.php" method="post" name="add" enctype="multipart/form-data">

<p id="bio" style="display:none;"><label class="left">Bio</label><textarea name="bio"     rows="10" cols="50" class="contact"></textarea></p> 

<p class="submit" style="text-align:center;"><input type="submit" name="add" value="Submit" /></p>

</form>
```

I know that i have to use str_replace, but I just don't know where to use it. I think I'm getting confused as to when the entered information will be formatted.

Comment: Applying formatting on the client is a poor idea. Storing formatted data (instead of raw data) in the database is a poor idea (except as a cache). Allowing HTML in the address is a poor idea (it renders you vulnerable to XSS attacks unless you do some relatively (compared to simply escaping the text) expensive filtering) Add the `<br>` elements when you insert the address into the HTML, and do it with server side code.

Comment: this form is on the admin side and that webpage is secure and can only be accessed by people who have permissions. I just want any line breaks to be changed into <br/> tags. [THIS](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2813071/remove-line-breaks-and-add-br-tags-in-php) is what i want but i just don't know when or how to apply it.

Comment: You aren't just trusting people to not be malicious, you are also trusting them to not make mistakes. Do this server side. It is where you are (or, at least, should be) doing all your conversion to HTML already, so do it in the same place.

Answer (score 10):

You should not alter data, when saving it (beside escaping of unwanted chars, and date-conversions to your desired format (UTC or else)). Instead alter it, when displaying it.

So, save it in the database with the `\n`s (allowing to easily edit it later on) and when displaying the data, simple use `nl2br()` around the variable, holding the text from the database.

Otherwise - upon edit - you would need to convert `<br>` back to `\n`s and again to `<br>`s upon save.

Comment: alright, so are you saying that i should keep this how it is here as the same. But when I display the information then i should use the nl2br()?

Comment: @user2441391 The database does not care WHAT you save. But saving the plain version is easier, when you want to allow modifications. Like, if you want to display 3x value (user enters 1 -> display 3), you are going to save "value" (1), and do the 3x, when displaying it. Then you can modify "value" without any reverse calculation. And if you FINALLY want to display `4x` - you just need to change the display function, rather than updating the whole database.

Comment: ok, i understand. I have a question. Since the database does not care what you save. If I save `A    B` , will it not save as "A B" or "AB" in the database?

Comment: i'm trying to show the first "A B" with 5 spaces. What i'm trying to say is that will all the extra spaces be removed?

Comment: @user2441391 don't get that. If the user enters `A B` -> Store `A B`. When you want to remove whitespaces for displaying, remove it. So, when the user entered `A B` or `A  _____ B` - the information is preserved. Just both are displayed as `AB`

Comment: alright, so in a form when i submit some information with some break lines then in the database they are saved with a `/n` , right? and when i want to display that data i just find the `/n ` and replace them with `<br />` . Is that correct?

Comment: @user2441391 Both ways might work. The one you described is just the "cleaner" solution I would prefer.